# Select all where field contains string separated by comma

Tags: mysql

I have a field called 'tags' containing a comma delimited list of tags, such as:

```
ios, ios development, freelance, new_project
```

I would like to query the field to check to see if the value 'ios' is in the comma delimited list. Please could you tell me how I could do this?

Comment: Consider normalizing your schema and keeping tags in a separate table, one tag per row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With MySQL, you can use `FIND_IN_SET()`:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE FIND_IN_SET('ios ', tags) > 0;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

Note that `FIND_IN_SET` expects strings to be *comma* separated, not *comma and space* separated. So you might have problems with the last tag. The really best way would be to *normalize the table*; otherwise you might expunge spaces from the `tags` column; finally you can work around the problem by adding a space to the `tags` column:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE FIND_IN_SET('ios ', CONCAT(tags,' ')) > 0;
```

If the number of tags is limited, you might consider converting the column to a `SET`. This will greatly improve efficiency.

**UPDATE**

Except that I got the spaces *wrong*. They are *before* the strings and not after.

So:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE FIND_IN_SET(' ios', CONCAT(' ', tags)) > 0;
```

But again, get rid of those spaces - they're nothing but trouble :-)

**UPDATE 2**

The above works, okay. But, that's almost all you can say in my favour. Not only the solution is quite *in*efficient, it also makes the system next to unmaintainable (been there, done that, got the T-Shirt and a chewed-out ass underneath same). So I'll now harp a bit in favour of normalization, i.e., having at least these two more tables:

```
CREATE TABLE tags ( id      INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
                    tagName varchar(32) // I'm a bit of a cheapskate
);
CREATE TABLE has_tag ( tableid INTEGER, tagid INTEGER );
```

How much is this better? Let me count the ways.

- you can easily add more flexible queries ("has all tags in iOS, C++, ..." or "has at least three tags among these: ( iOS, Python, SQL, .NET, Haskell )". Yes, you can do this with `FIND_IN_SET`,  but trust me, you *will not enjoy it*.
- you have a *controlled dictionary* of tags, which empowers you to check whether any tag is known (as well as easily generate lists such as drop-down combo boxes, or -- did anybody say 'jQuery Autocomplete'?).
- saves some disk real estate (tags are written once)
- searches are *fast*. If you already know the tags you're looking for and pre-compile them into tag IDs, they will leave SQL rubber scorch marks on the pavement when running (indexed search for an *integer* value!). And tags that won't compile *will not be there*, and you will know this even before the search starts.
- makes much easier to rename tags
- can hold *any number* of tags (you risk having some tag truncated to 'iOS Developm' sooner or later...)

I believe that the "CSV field" is cens(or)ed among the *SQL Antipatterns* ( http://pragprog.com/book/bksqla/sql-antipatterns ), and for good reason.

Comment: I've tried with a sample table and it works. What values were in one of the rows which were NOT selected?

Comment: The value I am trying to select is now 'iOS Development'. Row1: `iOS Development, Freelancing`. Row2: `Open Source, MKNetwork, iOS Development, Freelancing`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple method that works well for comma-delimited lists:

```
select *
  from mytable
 where concat(', ', tags, ',') like concat(', %ios%,')
```

Answer (score 0):

first (simple):

```
WHERE tags LIKE '%ios,%'
```

Comment: What if `ios` happens to be the last item in the list?

Comment: '%' does include EMPTY string as pattern...
if you want to select at least ONE you have to use '_%'

Comment: Eh? No I mean if the tags were `ios development, freelance, new_project, ios`, there would be no match, because `ios,` does not exactly appear anywhere in the tag list, even though `ios` is technically a valid tag.  That's specifically why I use the trick of inserting an extra `,` at the beginning and end, and then matching for commas at both ends to make sure the matching works correctly even for tags at the beginning or end of the list. I've solved this problem before :)

Comment: ahhhhh sry! i got it... you mean the COMMA... regex? 
gimme a sec to figure out, if set-operations will be work.

Comment: SELECT * FROM test.test1 WHERE FIND_IN_SET('ios', tags);

@lsemi is TOTALLY right with his solution!

Comment: Agreed, using `FIND_IN_SET` is much better :)