# mysql search database against a query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm looking for a way to compare database values against a given query using MySql
(in oppose of searching the query in the db)

---

I will elaborate:
I have a table that holds comma separated keywords and a result for each block of keywords
for example :

col 1                      col 2

Mercedes,BMW,Subaru        car

Marlboro,Winston           cigarette

---

today im taking the user query (for example - Marlboroligt)
as you can see if i will search for the value 'Marlboroligt' in the db i will get no results.

for that matter i want to search 'Marlboro' from the db inside the query and return 'cigarette'

Hope my explanation is sufficient and that this is actually possible :-).

Comment: Normalize your db would make things easier. Fields with comma separated values are really a mess...

Comment: normalization isn't always an option.

Comment: well lets say that i separated the first column and it is now a single keyword only , how will i do the thing now ?

Comment: oh i see the FIND_IN_SET method

Answer (score 0):

Normalization will help you the most. Otherwise, search in comma delimited fields is discussed here:

[Select all where field contains string separated by comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12149218/select-all-where-field-contains-string-separated-by-comma)

...and to search 'Marlboroligt' instead of 'Marlboro Light', you can try looking into the `LEVENSHTEIN` function, or maybe the Soundex encoding (which looks like too little bang for too large a buck, but then again, maybe...).

Answer (score 0):

I see the following possible solutions:

- setup a keyword-search engine like [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) and use it to search keywords in your db
- normalize your db - col1 must contain the only keyword
- use *like* patterns

  select col2 from mytable where col1 like "%Marlboro%"

*like* slows down your application and can have substring-related issues.